# Hadoop Oozie CPU utilization high

Tags: hadoop, cpu, oozie, high-availability

I'm currently running 20 concurrent jobs in OOZIE and noticed that oozie is hitting 400% of CPU utilization in the VM. How to reduce the load? Will adding another oozie server reduce the load on it?

Answer (score 0):

> Will adding another oozie server reduce the load

Unfortunately, no. Oozie is a single service.

You could offload other services like the Oozie database to a separate machine. Oozie does not need to be installed on a datanode / namenode / resource manager machine since it communicates with YARN over REST